# PHP var_dump on array returns NULL when called inside function

Tags: php, arrays, null

I have a PHP-file looking something like this:

```
<?php
    $ERRORS = array(
        '0' => "Unauthorized access",
        '1' => "Wrong username / password",
        '2' => "Missing field(s)",
        '3' => "Passwords do not match!"
    );

    var_dump($ERRORS);

    function getErrorMessage($errorCode){
        var_dump($ERRORS);

        // More code to output the corresponding message

    }
?>
```

When executed, the first `var_dump($ERRORS)` outputs

> array(4) { [0]=> string(19) "Unauthorized access" [1]=> string(25) "Wrong username / password" [2]=> string(16) "Missing field(s)" [3]=> string(23) "Passwords do not match!" }

But the the `var_dump` inside the function returns `NULL`

What is the cause of this, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You should really read up on how scoping works in PHP

Comment: It looks like you are coming from a javascript background where this is acceptable, but $ERRORS isn't in the same scope as `getErrorMessage()`

Comment: I guess I somewhat come from JS, but yeah, I had no idea that PHP  scoping was so different, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP global in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

Comment: The real answer is: Don't do use `global` pass the variable as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your variable scope is local. To access it inside function. You need to make it global.

```
<?php
    global $ERRORS;
    $ERRORS = array(
        '0' => "Unauthorized access",
        '1' => "Wrong username / password",
        '2' => "Missing field(s)",
        '3' => "Passwords do not match!"
    );

    var_dump($ERRORS);

    function getErrorMessage($errorCode){
        global $ERRORS;
        var_dump($ERRORS);

        // More code to output the corresponding message

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why the double `global $ERRORS;` ?

Comment: It will help him understand what is going on. Although we can omit the global on the outside.

Comment: This answer does not use best practices.  Please read possible-duplicate link under question.  Just because "it works like a charm" doesn't mean it is what _should_ be done.

Comment: `globals` is trash IMO. Dependency injection is better.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `global` I would use `normal` way

```
<?php
    $ERRORS = array(
        '0' => "Unauthorized access",
        '1' => "Wrong username / password",
        '2' => "Missing field(s)",
        '3' => "Passwords do not match!"
    );

    var_dump($ERRORS);

    function getErrorMessage($errorCode, $ERRORS)
    {
        var_dump($ERRORS);

        // More code to output the corresponding message

    }
```

Global is trash IMO, because there is no way to tell were it was set.  Sure in a single file that seems fine, but when you have a site composed of hundreds of files and 10s of thousands of lines of code, it can be near impossible to find where a global was set or changed. (I've spent hundreds of hours digging though older 3rd party code for stuff like that )

Personally I avoid using it at all cost.

It would be even better to make this a class with a getErrors() method, that's how I would do it ( except I would build an actual \Exception class )

```
final class AppError
{
    //constant value should match array key for the error
    /* 
      Unknown Error was intentionally left out, this is for internal                     
      use granted with only 4 errors and the constants it would be
      hard to give an invalid error code, but as the class grows
      we are future proofing it.
    */

    const ER_ACCESS     = 0;
    const ER_LOGIN       = 1;  //this is a login error it seems, and this looks better / is shorter then ER_USER_PASS
    const ER_MISSING    = 2;
    const ER_PASSWORD   = 3;

    public static $ERRORS = [
        '-1' => "Unknown Error", //I added this 
      //'0' => "No Error", //I changed this number
        '1' => "Unauthorized access", 
        '2' => "Wrong username / password",
        '3' => "Missing field(s)",
        '4' => "Passwords do not match!"  //isn't this the wrong password
    ];

    private function __construct(){ //no construction }

    public static function getErrors( $code = null)
    {
       //on null return all
       if(in_null($code))
          return self::$ERRORS; 

       //on false or 0 return empty string
       if(!$code) return '';
       /*
          Example:
          Consider this, you could have a function that checks for 
          errors and returns an error code or false on no errors. So,
          by returning an empty string here we can avoid having to check 
          before passing that into this class.
       */

       //code not set in array = unknown error
       if(!isset(self::$ERRORS[$code]))
           return self::$ERRORS['-1']; 

       return self::$ERRORS[$code];
    }

}
```

Then

```
var_dump( AppError::getErrors() );

function getErrorMessage($errorCode)
{
    var_dump( AppError::getErrors() );

    // More code to output the corresponding message

}
```

And now you can do this too ( as a bonus )

```
var_dump(AppError::getErrors(0)); //"Wrong username"
```

Now you may wonder why I added these `const E_* = #`?

1. If you fill your code up with things like the above example( numbered codes). And then later after you add a bunch of errors, you decide to organize them and renumber them you will have to look through all your code and find those number and fix them. Using a constant we don't care what value the constant is, it could be `pumpernickel` and it wouldn't matter.
2. it's hard to look at `0` and know its a `Unauthorized access` error.  So, by using the constants we can improve the readability of the code overall.  When you see `ER_ACCESS` instead of `0` it will be clear what it is.

*Summery* this moves all the dependencies inside of the class were we can keep everything tidy. Basically it's a separation of concerns, your code outside the class shouldn't care what the value of that error code is, mainly you just want the correct string message. How that's done is a black box, the implementation of which doesn't matter to the rest of your application.

You may also notice I used `final` for the class and a `private` constructor. These protect the class from being modified later or used in a way it's not intended. Final means the class cannot be extended, and therefor none of the methods can be modified by child class. PHP will throw an error if you try to create a new instance of the class with `new AppError()`. This means the only way to access the methods in the class is with the static call `class::method()`.

It's kind of a picky thing, but I thought I would do it as I would wright the class in the `real` for sake of completeness.  I've also went a bit above and beyond with the explanation, that's because I have no idea of your level of Object Oriented Programming and using a class as I outlined is IMO the correct way to do this.

Now its very simple to use the constants( mirroring the above example )

```
var_dump(AppError::getErrors(AppError::ER_ACCESS)); //"Unauthorized access"
```

*Note*  I didn't test any of this so if there are any syntax errors, forgive me.

The last thing I would suggest is to take a look at how Exceptions work in php, all the cool kids use them, and it will let you do things like `throw` and `catch` errors.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

P.S. the question was already answered when I wrote this ( I don't care about the points ) just the OP seemed to be nice and had a well written question, so I thought I would put something comprehensive together to show the OOP possibilities.

Enjoy!